# Can confidence intervals detect outliers?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, sample-size

I'm wondering what a standard approach for this situation is:

Suppose we have some small batch of samples $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$. If we are then given a new sample $x$, what can we say about the "reasonableness" of $x$?

As a concrete example, suppose our original samples are the prices for a phone plan. The new sample $x$ is the cost of my current phone plan, which I would like to show is "reasonable".

How to go about this? I could calculate the sample standard deviation of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ and then see how many standard deviations $x$ is from the sample mean, but I'm not sure how to conclude anything from this. Similarly, I'm not sure if a confidence interval can be used to test new points.

Comment: Note that CIs directly span a multiple of standard errors, not standard deviations.

Comment: Also look at *prediction intervals*.

Comment: The classical method of outlier detection works exactly like you proposed. Compute the standard deviation and dismiss points that are two far away from the mean (in terms of standard deviation units). Confidence intervals are not well suited for this as they are statements about parameters not about data.

Comment: But how many standard deviations away from the mean are considered to be "too far away"?